# Read FTP files without local folder in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ftp

I'm using [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2884/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-ftp-task-for-data-exchange/) as a reference for reading a file from FTP folder. But this tutorial says that the files in the FTP folder should be loaded in a local folder and only then it can be used for processing using other tasks in SSIS.

My question is, Is it possible to read a file directly from the FTP folder without storing them in the local folder and do the ETL operations in SISS?

Any advice would be helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with standard SSIS components. Standard SSIS allows you to download a file from FTP server to a local folder, and use local CSV-like file as a data source. Standard Flat File Source or XML Source allows only local and mapped network folders as sources for the source File.

If you really want to combine FTP download and Data source in single data source, you can write your own Script Source Component with C# or VB.NET. It will require more efforts than using standard two components.